# Why does this script tag not run this script on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the simple script i'm trying to run, i've also tried it with only the alert but it just doesn't work. If it's any help, it's part of a html block i'm echoing from a php script.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">    
    alert(\'test\');      
    JACS.show(document.getElementById(\'data_jacs\'),\'jacsStatic2\');                                                                                     
</script>
```

I found the problem and it has nothing to do with the script, it has everything to do with the php file i'm echoing it from being loaded with AJAX. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you escaping the single quotes?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example on jQuery(jquery.net) please

Comment: i'm escaping the single quotes because i'm already using single quotes for the echo, looks like echo '<some html> <script>
alert(\'test\')</script> <some more html>'

Answer (score 1):

Might be more then one reason:

1. Don't use slashes:

   alert('test');
2. You're using JACS. Are you sure the JACS library is loaded by the time this script tag is being executed?

Comment: 1. I kinda have to since i'm using it in the middle of an echo that's delimited by ' to begin with.  2.Yep, it's loaded. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Also, even if I take out the JACS part and leave only alert("test"); in the script tag, it still won't run the alert.

Comment: `echo "alert(\"test\");"` will render a perfect `alert("test");`

Comment: only other thing that seems strange is the capital J in `text/Javascript`. try `text/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

it returns error so to execute it and catch exception you need to specify try catch block

```
<script>    
  alert('test');   
  try
  {   
     JACS.show(document.getElementById('data_jacs'),'jacsStatic2');                                                                                     
}
catch(err){
   alert(err);
}
</script>
```

it alerts an error **JACS library not defined.**

Comment: I've been using the JACS library for a while now, i doubt it has a problem. Besides, even if I use it with only the alert, it still won't run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code behind the  tag.

Or you can do:

```
window.onload=function(){
    alert(\'test\');      
    JACS.show(document.getElementById(\'data_jacs\'),\'jacsStatic2\');                                                                                     
}
```